# UILabel double text

Tags: xcode4, uilabel

I'm creating a UILabel this way and it works just fine the first time..

```
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(98, 286, 600, 180);
    UILabel *lblQuestionTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [lblQuestionTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblQuestionTitle setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0]];
    [lblQuestionTitle setText:labelText];
    [lblQuestionTitle setNumberOfLines:0];
    [lblQuestionTitle sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:lblQuestionTitle];
```

The problem is when I use this code later, the new text appears over the old text.. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reusing the code, simply overwrite the Label text.

```
[lblQuestionTitle setText:@"New label text!"];
```

If you really want an entire new button, simply set lblQuestionTitle to hidden before adding the new label

```
[lblQuestionTitle hidden:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work... Just calling [lblQuestionTitle setText:@"New label text!"]; gives me no text at all